# Remote Connect to OpenShift MySQL without Port Forwarding

Tags: openshift

I am trying to set up production and development environment for my web project hosted at Openshift PAAS.

I should be able to deploy my web application after final tests and changes to Openshift (production environment).

I set my development environment using GITHUB(Since I do not want other people to connect to openshift). 
How do they can connect to Openshift MYSQL server hosted at cloud without port forwarding.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to connect to the MySQL server that is hosted on your OpenShift application without using port forwarding.